# add image in horizontal scrollView not displaying images

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I have added some images in scroll view I got prom is images not displaying on scroll view so please help, my code is below.

```
-(void)addscroll
{
    CGFloat btnX = 160.0;
    int numberOfButton = 10;
    for (UIView *subview in scrollView.subviews) {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }

    for (int i = 1 ; i <= numberOfButton; i++)
    {
        UIImageView *img=[[UIImageView alloc]init];
        img.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"];
        //img.tag = i;
        //[button setTitle:@"Excavations" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        img.frame = CGRectMake(160.0, 200.0, 160.0, 40.0);
        [scrollView addSubview:img];
        btnX = btnX + 165.0;
    }
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(btnX + 50, 150);
}
```

Comment: what's the size of your scrollview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
-(void)addscroll
{
    CGFloat btnX = 160.0;
    int numberOfButton = 10;
    for (UIView *subview in scrollView.subviews) {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }

    for (int i = 1 ; i <= numberOfButton; i++)
    {
        UIImageView *img=[[UIImageView alloc]init];
        img.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"];
        img.frame = CGRectMake(btnX, 105, 160.0, 40.0);
        [scrollView addSubview:img];
        btnX = btnX + 165.0;
    }
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(btnX + 50, 150);
}
```

You set x of `img` frame to `160.0`, so all `img` will be added to the same position, change it to `btnX` and update `btnX` on each iteration. Next is `contentSize` of `scrollView`, its content height is set to 150 and `img` is added to y of 200. So content beyond the height of scrollview cannot be visible.

Answer (score 0):

You are calculating wrong frame of image view

```
    img.frame = CGRectMake(btnX, 200.0, 160.0, 40.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)addscroll
{
    CGFloat btnX = 160.0;
    int numberOfButton = 10;
    for (UIView *subview in scrollView.subviews) {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }

    for (int i = 0 ; i < numberOfButton; i++)
    {
        UIImageView *img=[[UIImageView alloc]init];
        img.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"];
        //img.tag = i;
        //[button setTitle:@"Excavations" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        img.frame = CGRectMake(i*btnX +10, 200.0, 160.0, 40.0);
        [scrollView addSubview:img];
    }
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake((btnX + 10)*numberOfButton, 160);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your scrollview's height is 150, and your buttons y value is 200, that means is out of visible frame.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code. Also make sure that img.image is not nil and "1.png" exists. You have limited the scroll to less than 200 while image start from 200 in y

-(void)addscroll

{

```
CGFloat btnX = 0;
int numberOfButton = 10;
for (UIView *subview in scrollView.subviews) {
    [subview removeFromSuperview];
}

for (int i = 1 ; i <= numberOfButton; i++)
{
    UIImageView *img=[[UIImageView alloc]init];
    img.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"];
    img.frame = CGRectMake(btnX, 200.0, 160.0, 40.0);
    [scrollView addSubview:img];
    btnX = btnX + 165.0;
}
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(btnX + 50, 250);}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `img.frame = CGRectMake(160.0, 0, 160.0, 40.0);`

By setting y = 200, you are making it out of visible parent's frame. Scroll's max height is 198, your image's y origin should be before that in order to make subview visible.